# FilesMatch for .htaccess with a DirectoryIndex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to configure my URLs such that my .htaccess file enables basic authentication on only my landing page "www.domain.com", which is equivalent to "www.domain.com/index.html". However, I'm currently doing a FilesMatch as follows:

```
<FilesMatch "index.html>
    ...basic authentication configs...
</FilesMatch>
```

This doesn't work because when I try to access just "www.domain.com", I get a not-authenticated error, as the basic auth prompt doesn't show up since it's configured to only show up when I access "wwww.domain.com/index. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which file is the main entrance of your app

> DirectoryIndex index.html

Perhaps, it could work !